# require password every time CryptSignMessage() called

Tags: c++, windows, digital-signature

We are implementing digital signatures with microsoft wincrypt in an un-managed c++ project using 
certificates stored on a USB token.

Everything works as expected, except when a user goes through the process multiple times they are only required to enter their certificate password the first time unless our application is closed and restarted.

We need for the user to be challenged with their password every time they sign some data.  Is there a way to "reset" the process?

```
CertOpenSystemStore(NULL,"MY");
CertEnumCertificatesInStore(); // until we find the certificate we want
CryptSignMessage(); // this brings up the password dialog box the first time, but not again
// edited to show closing store and freeing context
CertCloseStore();
CertFreeCertificateContext();
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching of the password is controlled by the driver of the USB device. Usually this is configurable via some UI application that is shipped with the device and its drivers.

As a last resort you can put the signing procedure to a separate EXE and run it each time you need to sign the data. This way the separate process will be called for each signing operation and the password will not be cached.